# Jmeter posting on UI and capturing header values

Tags: jmeter

I want to post my username and password details on the login screen of a UI application and get the header values from it post authentication.

Comment: Please specify the type and sample of your login requests to server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Beanshell preprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to set your username and password as variables. To post your login details add the values in webservice or in post parameters as ${username} (eg: `http://url?user=?${username}`)

Use [Regular expression extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) to extract values from post authentication response.